# Custom Outlook Macro only runs in VBA editor

Tags: vba, outlook

I've created a Macro based on a blog post that only successfully runs in the VBA editor. When I run it from Outlook itself, nothing happens.  Maybe you can see something obvious that I'm missing.

1. Pressed `Alt`+`F11` to open the editor.
2. Named the module and pasted in the code.
3. Compiled and run. The e-mail in question opened in HTML-format as expected.
4. Closed the editor and added the button to the toolbar I wanted.  Nothing happens.
5. Returned to the VBA editor and run the code.  It works as expected.
6. Closed and re-opened Outlook to try the button again.  Nothing happens.

Here's the code, with a screenshot of the code in the editor to follow.

```vb
Sub ReplyInHtmlFormat()
    Dim olSel As Selection
    Dim oMail As MailItem
    Dim oReply As MailItem

    Set olSel = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    Set oMail = olSel.Item(1)

    If oMail.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain Or olFormatRichText Or olFormatUnspecified Then
       oMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
       oMail.Save
    End If

    Set oReply = oMail.Reply
    oReply.Display

    Set olSel = Nothing
    Set oMail = Nothing
    Set oReply = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image: VBA editor]

Comment: `If oMail.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain Or olFormatRichText Or olFormatUnspecified` isn't valid... you need to repeat the `olMail.BodyFormat =` for each condition, or use `Select Case` here.

Comment: or `If oMail.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check the macro permissions to make sure it is allowed to run.  I hope that helps!  ;-)

Comment: If the code can be run under the debugger, permissions are ok.

Comment: Yep. This was it.  Somehow macros kept getting disabled. I had to manually allow all macros for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `MsgBox` statement outside of any `If` statement and you will be able to understand whether it is actually running or not when you click a button added to the toolbar.

Also, I'd recommend adding an error-handling routine to the function:

```
Public Sub OnErrorDemo()
   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler   ' Enable error-handling routine.
   Dim x, y, z As Integer
   x = 50
   y = 0
   z = x / y   ' Divide by ZERO Error Raises

   ErrorHandler:    ' Error-handling routine.
   Select Case Err.Number   ' Evaluate error number.
      Case 10   ' Divide by zero error
         MsgBox ("You attempted to divide by zero!")
      Case Else
         MsgBox "UNKNOWN ERROR  - Error# " & Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description
   End Select
   Resume Next
End Sub
```

So, you will be aware of any issues if any.